# Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:32778)

Tags: python, java, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, collect

I have pyspark dataframe like this:

```
x     y
656  78
766  87
677  63
.    .
.    .
.    .
```

Where I have around 72 million rows. Now I want to plot histogram for this pyspark df for column `y`.
I have tried `collect()` and `toPandas()`.
But `collect` method is throwing error.

```
[val.y for val in df.select('y').collect()]

Out:
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:32778)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 535, in collect
    sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
  File "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 336, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o180.collectToPython

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 929, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1067, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
    534         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 535             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    536         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    335                 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}".
--> 336                 format(target_id, ".", name))
    337     else:

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o180.collectToPython

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in _get_connection(self)
    928         try:
--> 929             connection = self.deque.pop()
    930         except IndexError:

IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in start(self)
   1066         try:
-> 1067             self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
   1068             self.stream = self.socket.makefile("rb")

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Py4JNetworkError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_29360/1990936990.py in <module>
----> 1 non_routine_saving = [val.savingsPercent for val in non_routine.select('savingsPercent').collect()]

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
    533         """
    534         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 535             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    536         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    537 

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/traceback_utils.py in __exit__(self, type, value, tb)
     76         SCCallSiteSync._spark_stack_depth -= 1
     77         if SCCallSiteSync._spark_stack_depth == 0:
---> 78             self._context._jsc.setCallSite(None)

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1253             proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1254 
-> 1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
   1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in send_command(self, command, retry, binary)
    981          if `binary` is `True`.
    982         """
--> 983         connection = self._get_connection()
    984         try:
    985             response = connection.send_command(command)

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in _get_connection(self)
    929             connection = self.deque.pop()
    930         except IndexError:
--> 931             connection = self._create_connection()
    932         return connection
    933 

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in _create_connection(self)
    935         connection = GatewayConnection(
    936             self.gateway_parameters, self.gateway_property)
--> 937         connection.start()
    938         return connection
    939 

/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in start(self)
   1077                 "server ({0}:{1})".format(self.address, self.port)
   1078             logger.exception(msg)
-> 1079             raise Py4JNetworkError(msg, e)
   1080 
   1081     def _authenticate_connection(self):

Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:32778)
```

Spark Config:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from platform import python_version
import os

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import csv
import pickle as pkl
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, countDistinct


from pyspark.sql.window import Window

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

# Constants for application
APPLICATION_NAME = "p13n_data_introduction"
CHECKPOINT_DIRECTORY = "gs://p13n-storage2/user/s1b0jec"

spark_config = {}
spark_config["spark.executor.memory"] = "32G"
# spark_config["spark.executor.memoryOverhead"] = "4G"
spark_config["spark.executor.cores"] = "32"
spark_config["spark.driver.memory"] = "32G"
# spark_config["spark.shuffle.memoryFraction"] = "0" 


# Executor config
spark_config["spark.dyamicAllocation.enable"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors"] = "100"
spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors"] = "300"

spark_config["spark.submit.deployMode"] = "client"
spark_config["spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.yarn.queue"] = "default"
spark_config["spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode"] = "nonstrict"
spark_config["spark.hadoop.hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode"] = "100"

spark_config["spark.yarn.dist.archives"] = "gs://p13n-storage2/user/s1b0jec/envs/spark.zip#mypython"
# spark_config["spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = 

# spark_config["spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = "python" # For client mode it's the default `python` executable, whereas for cluster mode we use the distributed python environment

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = "./mypython/spark/bin/python"
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = "python"

spark_config["spark.jars"] = "/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/apache-hive-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/opt/lib/bfdms-ien/dp1.5/lib/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar"
spark_conf = SparkConf().setAll(spark_config.items())


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(APPLICATION_NAME) \
    .config(conf=spark_conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

print("Spark session created: ", spark.sparkContext.applicationId)
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(CHECKPOINT_DIRECTORY)

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: `[Errno 111] Connection refused` - The server you are trying to connect to is not running, or is not running on that port.

Comment: @JimGarrison when I load the different file in same place, it's running fine, it's just this file which is throwing error.